# Altering ActionBar from Fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to make two minor changes to an Activity's `ActionBar` from a `Fragment`.

The parent FragmentActivity's `onCreateOptionMenu` and `onPrepareOptions` handle the menu across the app.

However, in the containing main `Fragment` view,  I want the `ActionBar` title to change for the sake of navigation.  Each time the `Fragment` changes.

Also,  in one instance, I want to add a single menu item as defined in the layout. I rather not duplicate code for this part,  do I have to `override` the same methods and set up entire menu again,  including `onOptionSelected`?  Or...?

Edit:

On my menu `xml` layout, I have this item:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/Add"
        android:title="Add Items"/>
```

This item needs to be seen in the `ActionBar` only for one particular `Fragment`.  The rest of the menu is identical to what should be seen for the rest of the app.  In the fragment where I need this new item, do I have to also do `onCreateOptionsMenu`,  `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, and `onOptionsItemSelected` all over again and duplicate thee OTHER menu items as well?  Or can I `override` those in the `Fragment` and just pop that one extra menu item in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered what I needed for part 2.

Putting this in onActivityCreated:

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

And then adding this too:

```
 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());

        MenuItem Add = menu.findItem(R.id.Add);
        Add.setVisible(true);


    }
```

The parent Activity sets the `R.id.Add` as invisible by default.

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle();
```

or

```
getActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle();
```

1. more clarification please :)

Comment: Added a bit more info there for you... I will try this first part and test.

Comment: yes, in onActivityCreated(). Regarding the menu - I don't know the answer, you can just try and check yourself ;)